# Why is only one plot exponential and the rest are linear in matlab? (ODE15s)

Tags: matlab, graph, ode

I'm using ODE15s function on Matlab 2018 to model an epidemic (SIR model). The output should show the population in three groups over time:  Susceptible, Infected, and Recovered. The following equations are what are used by epidemiologists to describe the recovery model. This code is in a separate file that will be used in the main file.

```
function dYdt=EpiDiff(t,Y) 
 %dYdt=zeros(3,1);

i=10^5; %infection rate 
r=0.05; %recovery rate 
b=5e-5; %birth rate 
S=Y(1);
Inf=Y(2);
R=Y(3);

 dYdt(1)=(i*Inf*S)+(r*Inf);
 dYdt(2)=-(i*Inf*S)+(b*(Inf+S+R));
 dYdt(3)=r*Inf;

 dYdt=[dYdt(1);dYdt(2);dYdt(3)];
%If this final line isn't included, an error occurs about the matrix size.
end
```

Then the main code has the ode15s code that uses the function. I initially used ode45 (recommended it try first) but it was too stiff.

```
options=odeset('OutputFcn','odeplot','Outputsel',[0,45000]); 
[t,Y]=ode15s('EpiDiff',linspace(t_0,t_final,n_points),[300 30000 400000]); 

hold on

plot(t,Y(:,1),'-')
plot(t,Y(:,2),'-')
plot(t,Y(:,3),'-')

title('Population against Time (Days)') 

legend('Susceptibles','Infected','Recovered');

xlabel('Time (Days)') 
 ylabel('Population') 
hold off
```

When using the plot function, the following occurs:
[Link to graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue31d.jpg)

Why does the other two plots show up as a straight line? They're supposed to exponential, not linear...

Comment: You seem to have mixed up the components. The second equation looks like the change in S should be, the first equation like the Inf change should be. Also, the recovered change should be subtracted from the infected, not added.

Comment: Is your infection rate really 1e+5 and not 1e-5? Are the initial values really in the SIR order? Is a time span of over 100 years really realistic?